# get dropdown text from bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to get dropdown text value from bootstrap modal, when i call val() it done nicely, but when i call text() to retrieve dropdown text, it is returning stack of dropdown text

this my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Large modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".category-modal">Select Category</button>
        
        <!-- hidden fields to store modal result in -->
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="main-pages" class="col-lg-4 control-label">this should contain index from page dropdown : </label>
        <input type="text" id="main-pages">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="main-sub-pages" class="col-lg-4 control-label">this should contain text from sub-page dropdown : </label>
        <input type="text" id="main-sub-pages">
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade category-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Category</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">   
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <h4>Pages</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <h4>Sub Pages</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="text-center"></div>
                                        <h4></h4>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <select  id="pages" name="pages" class="form-control" size="6">
                                            <option value="1">Hello</option>
                                            <option value="2">Kon'nichiwa</option>
                                            <option value="3">Assalamualaikum</option>
                                            <option value="4">Annyeonghaseyo</option>
                                            <option value="5">Ciao</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <select  id="sub-pages" name="pages" class="form-control" size="6">
                                            <option value="1">Hello</option>
                                            <option value="2">Kon'nichiwa</option>
                                            <option value="3">Assalamualaikum</option>
                                            <option value="4">Annyeonghaseyo</option>
                                            <option value="5">Ciao</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="login()">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                  

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //called when user clicks login
            function login() {
                $("#main-pages").val($("#pages").val());
                $("#main-sub-pages").val($("#sub-pages").text());
                $(".category-modal").modal("hide");
            }
            
            $('.category-modal').on('hidden', function() {
                console.log('page : '+$("#main-pages").val());
                console.log('sub-page : '+$("#main-sub-pages").text());
            });
        </script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

note : you need to move the cursor on second text input to see dropdown text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!!

this is the solution

change this line

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //called when user clicks login
        function login() {
            $("#main-pages").val($("#pages").val());
            $("#main-sub-pages").val($("#sub-pages").text());
            $(".category-modal").modal("hide");
        }

        $('.category-modal').on('hidden', function() {
            console.log('page : '+$("#main-pages :selected").val());
            console.log('sub-page : '+$("#main-sub-pages :selected").text());
        });
    </script>
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //called when user clicks login
        function login() {
            var subPagesSelect = document.getElementById("sub-pages");
            var selectedText = subPagesSelect.options[subPagesSelect.selectedIndex].text;


            $("#main-pages").val($("#pages").val());
            $("#main-sub-pages").val(selectedText);
            $(".category-modal").modal("hide");

        }

        $('.category-modal').on('hidden', function() {
            console.log('page : '+$("#main-pages :selected").val());
            console.log('sub-page : '+$("#main-sub-pages :selected").text());
        });
    </script>
```

why i got all dropdown content, because what i call was an object not content of that object Correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 console.log('page : '+$("#main-pages").val());
 console.log('sub-page : '+$("#main-sub-pages").text());
```

To This

```
 console.log('page : '+$("#main-pages :selected").val());
 console.log('sub-page : '+$("#main-sub-pages :selected").text());
```